# Difference between these bitmask

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm wondering what's the difference of the bitmask below, and it what scenario you can use then.

```
int a  = 1;
int b  = 2;
int c  = 4;
int d  = 8;


int letters = a | b | d; 

int aviableLettersMask = //input some letter;  


if (letters & aviableLettersMask)
{

}

if ((letters & ~aviableLettersMask) == 0)
{

}
```

Thanks

Comment: why dont you check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: This question makes no sense to me

Comment: nothing to do with ios either. And doing random operations on numbers??

Comment: @AnoopVaidya ... because wikipedia makes a point to be less-than-encyclopedic, and at times, down-right incorrect? Perhaps you meant to link to [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the following:

The first once checks if there any letter in a `aviableLettersMask` presents in `letters`

The second one - if there is no other letters rather existing in `aviableLettersMask`.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression will be true iff `AviableLettersMask` contains at least one letter or `Letters`:

```
a|b|d & a|c = a  // ok
a|b|d & c = 0    // false
a|b|d & 0 = 0    // false
```

The second expression will equal 0 iff `AviableLettersMask` contains `Letters`:

```
a|b|d & ~(a|b)     = a|b|d & c|d = d  // false
a|b|d & ~(a|b|d)   = a|b|d & c   = 0  // ok
a|b|d & ~(a|b|c|d) = a|b|d & 0   = 0  // ok
```